# Excel files generated from iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

Is there something that i have to add to iReport so my file will be able to use all the columns of the excel file ?

Example :

When i download a big excel file(a report made with iReport)  from the application it uses all the excel columns from A to Z then it returns to the next line. I want to make it use the AA , AB , AC , AD ect columns that still available in excel because i don't want line returns.

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else needed the answer , i made the band's width  bigger (20000) to reach all the excel columns .

Problem resolved .